# Send asapMail without reloading page using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form that posts data to an aspMail file for delivery (works fine in current format), but would like to have the form data sent without having to re-direct to another page. Looks like Ajax is the way to proceed but I'm having a problem getting the setup to work.

Here's how I've changed the html:

Added:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {  
    $.ajax({  
        data: $(this).serialize(),  
        type: $(this).attr('post'),  
        url: $(this).attr('aspSend.asp'),  
        success: function(response) {  
            $('#created').html(response)  
        }  
    });  
});
```

Changed the form tag from:

```
<form name="myForm" action"aspSend.asp">
```

to:

```
<form name="myForm">
```

but now the emails don't arrive!!  Any suggestions?

Comment: What happened with unobtrusive JS?

Comment: @BalusC: I beg your pardon, but what do you mean

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd suggest you use Firebug to see exactly what's happening when you're hitting submit (is it actually posting? What's in the POST? What's the response?).

Aside from that, a few thoughts:

1. Make sure the form has an ID of myForm, as #myForm refers to the ID of an element, not the name of the element (so add id='myForm' to teh form tag)
2. I'm not sure about your attr tags to get the post information (maybe they work, but I haven't seen them look like that). I would do your post like this:

   ```
    $('#myForm').submit(function() {
       dataString = $("#myForm").serialize();
       $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "aspSend.asp",
       data: dataString,
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data) {
           if(data.status == "invalid"){
               $("#created").html("<div>Error</div>");
           } else {
                   $("#created").html("<div>Success</div>");
           }
       }
     });
   return false;
   ```

   });

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the code snippet with form-html is correct? You jQuery looks for an element with id myForm. But your form doesn't seem to have and id attribute.

So either add the id to form or try replacing this line

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
```

with this one

```
$('form[name="myForm"]').submit(function() {
```

And add a `return false;` statement after the ajax call

```
$.ajax({...});
return false;
```

Comment: This is correct, but there's a spelling mistake in the second code block

`$('for[name="myForm"').submit(function() {` should be `$('form[name="myForm"').submit(function() {`, and I personally wouldn't bother with the double quotes...